# Trouble with garbage chars in visual c++ file reading

Tags: visual-c++, file-io, g++

I am trying to read a text file using the following code:

```
void function readfile(char *inputfile) {
istream is;
int filesize = 0;

is.open(inputfile);
if (!is.is_open()) {
 return;
}
is.seekg(0, ios::end);
filesize = (int)is.tellg();
is.seekg(0, ios::beg);

char *buf = new char[filesize];
is.read(buf, filesize);
is.close();

cout << buf << endl;

delete[] buf;
return;
}
```

While in g++ (mac / macports) it works correctly (getting all contents into a dynamic allocated char* array), in Visual Studio C++ 2010, I get constant errors of this type: `Debug assertion failed: (unsigned)(c+1) <= 256, file isctype.c`.

The problem is that it opens the file but can't find a termination delimeter so when it reaches the eof it starts reading somewhere else (garbage characters). Using the `cout << buf;` I can see that the file is being read correctly in mac but in visual c++ it types more garbage chars. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let C++ standard library do the work for you:

```
void readfile(const char *inputfile) {
    std::ifstream is(inputfile);
    std::string buf(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is), {});
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
}
```

See, it's now also

- exception safe
- handles embedded NUL characters correctly

Note, of course you can use `vector` instead of `string` if you prefer (just change that one word)

Full demo: **[see it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2383cde32dc5e36c)**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

void readfile(const char *inputfile) {
    std::ifstream is(inputfile);
    std::string buf(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is), {});
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    readfile("main.cpp");
}
```

**Update** For C++11 challenged compilers (and showing how to use a vector):

Also **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e257bf50affa21da)**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

void readfile(const char *inputfile) {
    std::ifstream is(inputfile);
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> f(is), l;
    std::vector<char> buf(f, l);

    std::cout.write(buf.data(), buf.size());
}

int main()
{
    readfile("main.cpp");
}
```

Comment: Very insightful sehe. I am actually trying to achieve it as it was instructed by my course (which is part of a larger portion of a program). The problem is that we are not allowed to use string class, and I've been practicing more on my mac rather on the pc where visual studio is (and was supposed to be the main ide). I am mostly intrigued by the error generated by the mscompiler and is passed from the g++ one.

Comment: @Panagiotis Well, use the vector then :/ To do this (use `vector`, `std::cout.write` _and_ satisfy MSVC) see the updated answer (also [live online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e257bf50affa21da))

Answer (score 3):

Make your buffer one larger and add the terminating nul yourself.

Comment: alternatively, use `cout.write(buf, filesize)`, or just use the standard library all the way (see my answer)

Comment: Scott, I tried doing that afterwards I posted the question here, I also get the same error, even though in the writing stream (the other portion of this program) it works. Is it possible that it's a unicode thing? Even though the file is saved in ANSI from notepad?